# alter table/add columns in non native table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, druid, external-tables

I created a hive table with a storage handler and now I want to add a column to that table but it gives me below error:

```
[Code: 10134, SQL State: 42000]  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: 
SemanticException [Error 10134]: ALTER TABLE can only be used for [ADDPROPS, 
DROPPROPS] to a non-native table
```

As per the hive documentation any hive table you create with storage handler is non native table.

Here's a link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StorageHandlers

There is a JIRA case for enhancement is open with Apache for the same.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1240

For ex, I am using Druid Storage Handler in my case.

I created a hive table using:

```
CREATE TABLE druid_table_1
(`__time` TIMESTAMP, `dimension1` STRING, `metric1` int)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.druid.DruidStorageHandler';
```

and then I am trying to add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE druid_table_1 ADD COLUMNS (`dimension2` STRING);
```

With above approach I am getting an error.

Is there any other way to add a column to non native tables in hive without recreating it?

Comment: As the error says, `ADD COLUMN` isn't possible via Hive for those tables. You could attempt to manually edit the metastore, but you really shouldn't. What's the issue with dropping and recreating the table?

Comment: I am not seeing old data. in Hive documentation, I found a statement like "if  meta store is not managed by hive and you used any specific storage handler on create table, then when you drop it, you don't lose data", But with druid storage handler, if I drop a table and create with new schema, I am not seeing old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch is available in HDP 2.5+ from Hortonworks. Support for ADD columns has been added in ALTER statement.

Column can be added into druid table using ALTER table DDL in hive.
`ALTER TABLE  ADD COLUMNS (col_name data_type)`

There is no need to specify partition spec as these are druid backed hive tables and partition/storage is maintained by druid.